# Android textview gravity not applied if text is single line

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

i have weird problem, in my listview row i have textview and imageview, with weights 2 and 1 respectively, but if the textview text is single line or has less characters the imageview is not aligned to the right, please find my listview row layout code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="fruits"
        android:textColor="#80000000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cat_pic"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please find the image below
[image]

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_width`'s value of `TextView` with `0`

Comment: please try change android:layout_width="wrap_content" in your TextView and try remove the android:gravity= "center" of your LinearLayout

Comment: Hi, sorry has posted the wrong xml code, yes i am setting the 'layout_width' to 0dp,still same issue

Comment: @minos23 tried it, the text is now aligned to the left but still the imageview is not aligned to right

Comment: even if you remove gravity:center, still have the problem?

Comment: align your image to right and remove gravity to keep every row same

Answer (score 0):

I think is not appropriate to use weight in textview and edittext, I modified your code like this below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fruits"
        android:textColor="#80000000"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cat_pic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="6">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cat_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="Vegetables and Fruits"
    android:textColor="#80000000"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cat_pic"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:src="@drawable/guest_user_button_pressed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get view like this image ***just remove android:gravity="center"***

[image]

But i suggest you create xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cat_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cat_pic"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxvzabcdefghijk"
        android:textColor="#80000000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cat_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```